# Text and image in unordered list are overlapping

Tags: css

I want to move the text in this unordered list further to the right of my graphic, so they don't overlap. How do I do this?

Here's my code:

```
        .page p { line-height: 1.2em; }
        .page a { color: #1badd2; text-decoration: none; }
        .widget li  { 

            margin: 0;  
            padding: 2px 0px 8px 35px; 
            display: block; position: relative; 
            border-bottom: none;

            }



        .widget li:before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            background: url(http://bryancollins.eu/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
            height: 12px; width: 30px;
            position: absolute; top: 6px; left: 0px;
            }
```

You can see it in action here: bryan.collins.eu/wp

Comment: how does your html look?

Comment: ...and by the way, your link is not working... I suggest you rather add the relevant code though...

Comment: http://bryancollins.eu/wp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make room at the left by adding padding to the li element. The absolute positioning declared on the li:before selector causes it to be stacked above the li element.

Add this rule to this selector:

```
.featured-box ul li {
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

To vertically center the arrow a little more: Change the top value to 10px.

```
.widget li:before {
  top: 10px;
}
```

**Note**: You could easily have added this as a background image on the li without using the :before selector.

```
.featured-box .widget li {
  list-style: none;
  background: url("http://bryancollins.eu/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

Comment: I went for the second option. Thanks.